# VBA Excel Adding an incremental text, which also excludes blanks

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working on a user interactive sheet, which will look up values in an external database file, and post these to the user sheet, based on an ID number e.g. material number.

In this situation, I also want to add an "item number" for each material in the sheet, but without using a predefined excel table. Preferably I would paste only the text and value, and not the formula, but in the end, whatever gets the job done. I have tried two versions, but one does not skip blanks, the other wont paste the formula, as it gives me an "object" error and I cannot seem to identify why it won't accept this command. I am guessing .Formula has different requirements. (First line after If Not fndEntry Is Nothing....)

Below is the full code for the sheet, including all other statements not related to the issue.

I am aware that the range seems backwards, but I cannot seem to get excel to calculate logically, and therefore my row count is backwards. (Before anyone starts commenting on this) :) If you can solve why this is the case, I am more than eager to hear why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim material As String
Dim fndEntry As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim lr As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If Not Target.Column = 3 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C1000:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr < 20 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True

    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 20 To lr

material = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C" & i).Value

Set fndEntry = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("C:D").Find(What:=material)

If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then

    'wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(C2="""","""",CONCATENATE(Pos.;COUNTA($C$20:C20)))"
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("B" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("H" & fndEntry.Row).Value  'Product group
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("E" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("Q" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Available Stock
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("F" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("E" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Materiale name
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("G" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AJ" & fndEntry.Row).Value  'Marked for deletion
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("I" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("M" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Datasheet
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("K" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("P" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Lotsize
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("M" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("F" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Material type (FERT/HAWA)
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("N" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("N" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Date of Cost update
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("O" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("O" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Last change of cost data
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("P" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("K" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Stock category
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("Q" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("L" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'ABC code
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("R" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("V" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Construction weight Cu
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("S" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("W" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Construction weight Al
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("T" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("X" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Sales weight Cu
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("U" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("Y" & fndEntry.Row).Value   'Sales weight Al
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AC" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("Z" & fndEntry.Row).Value  'Construction weight PE
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AD" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AD" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'PE costs
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AE" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AA" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'Construction weight PVC
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AF" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AE" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'PVC costs
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AG" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AF" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'Other materials costs
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AH" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AB" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'Variable production costs
    wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("AI" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("AC" & fndEntry.Row).Value 'Fixed production costs

    End If
Next i

wb2.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Below is the line which is my main concern from the above code. As said, I would rather have VBA paste the final value "Pos.+number" instead of the formula, but whatever works.

wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(C2="""","""",CONCATENATE(Pos.;COUNTA($C$20:C20)))"

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: To find the last row in column c, you can use, more simply (one one line since this is a comment): `Dim lr as long: With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1"): lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row: End With`  To debug your error, I would need an example of your data that can reproduce it.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hi Ron, thank you for your comment, I have tried to specify more accurately which line is my main concern. I have submitted the entire code, to ensure all questions/issues possible could be considered.

I hope it is more clear what the issue is now.

Comment: As I wrote, without data, which you have not supplied, it is too much effort to try and figure out how to reproduce your problem, even with the code.  I would certainly use VBA rather than pasting a formula; however I note that in your formula, you are mixing commas and semicolon separators, and you also have an entry `Pos.` which is hard to understand.  I suggest, if you want to use a formula, to first enter the formula manually in a cell, and then use the `.Formula` property of that cell to construct your VBA statement.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure what data you are referring to. in short I want the below excel statement done by VBA: =IF(C20="""","""",CONCATENATE(""Pos."",COUNTA($C$20:C20)). Basically, It should write "pos. 1", "Pos. 2", "Pos.3", etc.

I have now gotten it to write the formula itself, but I would prefer if I could get VBA to do the formula itself.

Comment: The real dealbreaker from my skill level, is the skip of blanks, which I cannot seem to get done without the standard excel formula.

Comment: By "data" I mean the information in the workbooks, *sanitized* to remove confidential information -- preferably a link to the sample workbook that can be downloaded.  So that I may copy/paste your VBA macro and reproduce the issue.  It should not be difficult to skip blanks in VBA, but without seeing the data, it is difficult to craft a good solution.

Comment: I have uploaded a dummy file on below link, sanitized as you say. I hope this was what you meant.

https://spaces.hightail.com/space/x3scY

Comment: I have also added a dummy database file "Matcost.xls" to the shared folder.

Comment: The thing is, I want the user to be able to use the sheet with the lookup functionality, but also be able to insert their own values, should the material not exist in the database e.g. a brand new material which has not been created properly in the system. therefore the input can consist of a series of mat. numbers and also blank spaces, which the user could use a separator for personal overview reasons.

Comment: That information looks good for a start. I will be able to look at it later on today. Also useful would be examples of what you're talking about with regard to the user input and desired output.

Comment: However, you have marked another response as the answer. Does that mean you have all the information you need?

Comment: Hi Ron, no I marked it as an answer as he had answered part of my question, but I have unmarked it now. I was trying to be polite as both you and he pointed out my lack of clarity on the issue at hand. But I have unmarked it now.

Comment: User input could be something like:
433101204;
433101217;
433101220;
"blank";
5702959871964;
"blank";
"Manual calculation";
"Manual Calculation

Comment: @Smeltet since my code was assisting you in your original post (before you added more data), you can up-vote it (and not mark as answer). And then also other users will try help you with your updated post

Comment: Hi Ron, I have updated the user file, as I seem to have solved my blank space issue. I have inserted a check around my loop, where I check if the cell is empty. However, I still need to convert my IF formula to be calculated in VBA and inserted as a value only. (Column A in the user file)

Comment: OK, I have posted code which converts your `IF...` formula.  So far as the rest of your code and data, things still are not clear enough for me to work on that, but, if you have that part working to your satisfaction, there is no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a macro that will populate column A with values as per your Excel formula above.  You will note that

- you will have to change the workbook name to match whatever it is you are really using.
- the "work" is done using variant arrays.  This will run much faster than multiple accesses to the worksheet. Check out Chip Pearsons web page on [Variant Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for a more detailed discussion of this method.  But the speed difference is frequently 10-fold.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Totals()
    Dim vA As Variant, vC As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Const sPOS As String = "Pos. "

'You will need to change the workbook name according to your system
Const WBName As String = "Stackoverflow dummy (1).xlsm"

Set WS = Workbooks(WBName).Worksheets("Sagsnr.")

With WS
    vC = .Range(.Cells(20, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
End With

ReDim vA(1 To UBound(vC, 1), 1 To UBound(vC, 2))

J = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(vC)
    'Given that there are non-codes on the sheet in column C, you might need to check that the entry in
    '  Column C is an EAN Code rather than a null string.
    If vC(I, 1) <> "" Then
        J = J + 1
        vA(I, 1) = sPOS & J
    End If
Next I

With WS
    With .Range(.Cells(20, 1), .Cells(19 + UBound(vA, 1), 1))
        .Value = vA
        ' can add formatting properties if necessary)
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

to start, replace your :

```
lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C1000:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

with

```
lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row
```

and also:

```
material = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C" & i).Value
```

to:

```
material = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C:" & i).Value
```

Comment: the first suggestion, gives me an Error 13, "Mismatch"

Comment: i didn't notice you declared `lr` as an integer, because you are setting it at this line as a Range. What do you want lr to read ? is it trying to read the last row at Column C ?

Comment: lr should read the last row that is inserted/typed from in column C as it will then make a loop the number of times matching the number of "new" rows. Hence the later calculation of "i" as the difference between 20 and "lr". The rows in question start from C20.

Comment: Ok, that now changed my range, I still cannot use your last rewriting of material, but how does any of the above help me write the text + incremental value? Maybe you have a larger plan, I am just trying to understand. :)

Comment: @Smeltet this code was to remove the errors you were getting. you modified your post, and now you want something else.

Comment: Hi Shai, i appreciate your response, do not doubt that. From both yours and Rons comments, I gather I have not been clear enough about my multiple questions. I apologise.